# Search Center Master Page issue

Tags: search, publishing

I am working with a SharePoint 2010 Publishing site and need some help on some issues I am having as it relates to Search.  First, we are directing search results to a standard Sharepoint Search Center.  I have worked through the known issue that if you are using a custom master page you need to go through a series of steps to get it working with the Search Center layout and use a master specific for Search Center. [This is the article](http://blog.drisgill.com/2010/09/converting-custom-sharepoint-2010.html) that I referenced from Randy Drisgill.

I am using a standard sharepoint search delegate control in my site custom masterpage. I want this to appear in the master page of the search center but it doesn't.  ALthough the article above will get us a search box in the layout, my original search control in the master page is not present.  It is gone.  In fact, I do not even want search appearing in the layout.  Just as it should look in the master page.  How do I get this back?  What other options do I have?  The end goal is to get the same look and feel as other sites and be able to avoid contextual searching.  We want results back from all sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The search delegate control is loaded into the standard v4 master in a placeholder called PlaceHolderSearchArea:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

In the minimal.master, this placeholder is hidden in a panel at the bottom of the page, and does not include the delegate control:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderNavSpacer" runat="server" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" runat="server" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleLeftBorder" runat="server" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaSeparator" runat="server" />
</div>
```

To get the search box back into your search center, you are going to have to move the placeholder back into a visible place in your custom minimal.master, and you will need to include the delegate control.

Comment: Chris, We made a copy of the master that we are using for the other sites throughout the collection.  In this master, we added some edits that Randy explainds in his link that I posted.  Seeing that we don't hide the control in the master should this still be an issue.  It isn't hidden.  So why is it not showing in the Search Center?

Comment: Can you show a screen cap? Are the rest of the elements in your custom master being displayed? Try putting some static content in the placeholder in addition to the delegate control - is the placeholder loaded in the right place?

Comment: Yes the nav, footer no problem. Not sure this helps but this is the delegate that I lose in Master <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server" > <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" Version="4"/> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> Can you tell me what layout is used for the results.aspx?  We have an option of modifying the layout to avoid having the top nav jut out over the search control in the layout. THis might be acceptable by the client.

Comment: Chris, Thanks for your all your help on this. This was an issue with the results.aspx was overriding the searchcontrol.  When we removed the override we were good to go.

Comment: can u explain me more..i am also facing the same issue